# PHP Update many rows at the same time

Tags: php, mysqli, rows

I have a table with about 1000 rows inserted. They are categorized with their own ID and a specific code that make them unique.

A simple example would be:

```
id    |  site  | player    |  char          |
1     |  site 1| play1     |                |
2     |  site 2| play1     |                |
3     |  site 3| play1     |                |
4     |  site 4| play1     |                |
5     |  site 2| play2     |                |
6     |  site 2| play3     |                |
7     |  site 3| play2     |                |
8     |  site 4| play2     |                |
9     |  Site 1| play2     |                |
10    |  Site 2| play4     |                |
```

I'm in need to update the player information by site. So I select the site (example Site 2) and then it create a a form with the player name and a input box to insert the data:

Site 2 Edit:

```
Play1 - Char [INPUTBOX]
Play2 - Char [INPUTBOX]
Play3 - Char [INPUTBOX]
Play4 - Char [INPUTBOX]
```

What would be the best way, instead of create a code to update manually each one (and that would not be a good idea since it could be 1000 or 5000 edits at the same time) to edit all information placed in INPUTBOX for each "play" generated in the Site2?

There's any example code that could be benefic to use? Waiting for your suggestions. Thanks!

Note: I prefer to use this way since it's basically a copy/past update from another source so It's much quicky to update all data at the same time from the same site than update each user individually by site.

Comment: `for` statement is useful here -> http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php (FYI - add code you have tried or you won't get an answer)

Comment: I really don't need the code. I'm searching yet for the best way to do it. I already thought in a for loop, but how should I design the form so I can run them all while updating and update the right data? That's my question. I'm not getting the right way to design it.

Answer (score -1):

Your best bet is to pull your current player information out of the datatabase and then use the current information to append the new columns.

```
$db = mysqli_connect("host", "user", "pass", "name");
foreach($db->query("select * from table") as $row):
    $player = $row['player'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO table (player,char) VALUES ('$player', '$char')";
    if(!$db->query($sql)): echo $player." upload failed..."; endif;
endforeach;
```

So we're taking the names out for each, I suggest you maybe make an `Array` of Char's that each player will have and query it in an `ORDER BY` so it matches your array.

Hope this helped. (This way is automatic, it will do it for every player when the script is ran.)

Comment: Maybe if I use a new table to insert the data could be better? For example I have a table with all players and sites. In a new table I could insert all information with a simple for. Or even if my form input have the name as "player_site" I can implode it in two vars and then use that information to update (UPDATE *** WHERE player=$implode1 AND site=$implode2 ) . Could be a good way this second option?

Comment: The above code will do that for you, it will take out each player from the database, add a `char` to it and then put it in the new table.